# Handling a one-to-many relationship MongoDB schema design

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am currently designing the MongoDB schema for an event management system. The ER diagram is as follows:

[image]

The concept is fairly simple:

1. A company can create 1 or more events (estimating x500s of companies)
2. A client can attend 1 or more events from a multitude of companies (estimating x200 per client..also estimate x1000s of clients)

The is the classic many-to-many relationship, right?

Now I come from an RDBMS background, so my instincts on structuring a MongoDB schema might be incorrect. However I like MongoDB's flexible document nature and so I tried to come up with the following model structure:

```
Company model
{ 
  _id: <CompanyID1>,
  name: "Foo Bar",
  events: [<EventID1>, <EventID2>, ...]
}

Event model
{ _id: <EventID1>,
  name: "Rockestra",
  location: LocationSchema, // (model below)
  eventDate: "01/01/2019",
  clients: [<ClientID1>, <ClientID2>, ...]
}

Client model
{ _id: <ClientID1>,
  name: "Joe Borg"
}

Location model
{ _id: <LocationID1>,
  name: "London, UK"
}
```

My typical query scenarios would probably be:

1. List all events organised by a specific company (including location details)
2. List all registered clients for a particular event

Would this design and approach be a sensible one to use given the cardinality I stated above? I guess one of the pitfalls of this design is that I could not get the company details if I just query the events model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do

```
Company model
{ 
  _id: <CompanyID1>,
  name: "Foo Bar"
}

Event model
{ _id: <EventID1>,
  name: "Rockestra",
  location: LocationSchema, // embedded, not a reference
  eventDate: "01/01/2019",
  company: <CompanyID1>     // indexed reference.
}

Client model
{ _id: <ClientID1>,
  name: "Joe Borg",
  events: [<EventID1>, <EventID2>, ...] // with index on events
}
```

List all events organised by a specific company (including location details):

```
db.events.find({company:<CompanyID1>})
```

List all registered clients for a particular event:

```
db.clients.find({events:<EventID1>})
```

Comment: How does this query work, as in what is the second argument? db.companies.find({_id:<CompanyID1>}, {_id:0, events:1}.

Comment: I was typing quicker than thinking =) See my update. Of course it should be other way round. When you "List all events" it is `db.events.find`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not many-to-many unless a single event can be created by many companies.  It looks like you are describing one-to-many.

This is the way I'd approach it.

Company model

```
{ 
   _id:
   name: 
}
```

Client model

```
{ 
   _id: 
   name:
}
```

ClientEvents model

```
{
   _id
   clientId
   eventId
}
```

Event model

```
{ 
   _id:
   companyId:   
   name:
   locationId: 
   eventDate:
 }
```

Location model

```
{ 
   _id:
   name: "London, UK"
}
```

Comment: Your answer was actually my first instinct. However isn't the ClientEvents model a bit too RDBMS'ey? I mean, from what I read, I should not normalise the schema too much, and instead try to embed as much as I can in a single document.

Comment: That's tempting to do in Mongo because it "can" do it.  When I tried to embed all that stuff, I found myself writing 3-4 times the code to deal with it.   IMO, the relational structure is simple and straight-forward.  MongoDb will support it with aggregate $lookups.